# Are the image data augmentation generators in Keras randomly applied

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am working on an image classification problem and using data augmentation in Keras.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=2,
       horizontal_flip=True)
```

I would like to know if the `ImageDataGenerator`applies the transformation randomly to image patches. That is for example, rotation may be applied on one image, whilst flip may be applied to another image. I want to know if the decision to apply rotation or a flip is randomly determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having a look at [the relevant documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

There, it states:

> rotation_range: Int. Degree range for random rotations.
>
> ...
>
> horizontal_flip: Boolean. Randomly flip inputs horizontally.

Saying each of the operations is applied randomly, I would say, means your images will be generated sometime with and sometimes without the augmentation steps, independently from one another.

If that doesn't convince you, here is the [relevant snippet from the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L679):

```
if self.horizontal_flip:
    if np.random.random() < 0.5:
        x = flip_axis(x, img_col_axis)
```

The code for the rotation step is a little more involved, but contained within the same class that I liked above.